# Embedded loops in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to write a program that simulates the dice game bones. The idea is to roll five dice and get the lowest score possible--threes have a value of 0. Once the five dice are rolled the player/bot MUST select at least one die (or more) from the five and roll the rest. This is what's posing a problem to me. If there's no threes then the "keeper" array which I push the dice the bot keeps to ends up being empty, which necessitates an embedded loop. Since I'm pretty new to coding I really can't figure out a way to create an embedded loop that will ensure that at least one dice is designated as a keeper. For your sanity's sake I'll say that the "beta" version of this program I'll present now is intended to do the following: Create a bot that tries to get the lowest score on one round of bones. Ie. The dice are rolled once. Then he tries to pick the lowest score possible. If there are no threes (equivalent to 0) he picks ones. The problem I'm trying to solve is creating an embedded loop that ensures at least one die is selected for the keeper array. The code is mainly to demonstrate how ugly my solution is and give an idea for a better solution.

```
#rolls dice
srand
dice = []
5.times do 
  dice.push(rand(6)+1)
end
puts dice
puts " "

#initialize keeper and roll again arrays
i = 0
keeper = []
roll_again = []


#select any 3s from the dice roll and put them in keeper
dice.each do |d| 
  if d == 3 
    keeper.push(d)
  else
    i +=1  #dummy operation to keep if statement functioning, tragically ugly code
  end
end

#in the case that no threes were rolled, ones are selected
if keeper.length == 0
  dice.each do |f|
    if f == 1
      keeper.push(f)
    else
      i+= 1
    end
  end
else 
  i += 1
end

puts "Keeper:"
puts keeper
puts "Roll Again:"
puts roll_again
```

Comment: What if there are no threes or ones?

Comment: At this point it doesn't really matter. I would have proceeded to say: if the array is still empty select twos then fours etc etc. But without embedded loops i think this code would look terribly ugly. Unless there is no way of using embedded loops. Basically, to answer your question, the program is not currently written to simulate a round in its entirety. As long as the program can be tested whenever there are threes or ones in the array it is sufficient for my purposes--which is solely to learn how to code.

Comment: And what is `i` for? You increment it but don't seem to use it.

Comment: That's definitely the most ridiculous part of this code. All i could think of was to make the if statements work was include something as a dummy operation in the else statement. so i incremented a variable i knew i wouldn't use. It's bad coding, for sure.

Comment: Rubyists generally indent with 2 spaces, not 4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a beginner you are doing fine :-) I'll just show you some things that can help you with this exercise, you learn best by trying out different things and trying to understand them.

```
>> dice = [5,1,2,2,6,4] #=> [5, 1, 2, 2, 6, 4]
>> if (threes = dice.select { |d| d == 3 }).empty?
..   ones = dice.select { |d| d == 1 }
..   end #=> [1]
>> threes #=> []
>> ones #=> [1]
```

Another thing you can do is group the dice array:

```
>> dice.group_by { |d| d } #=> {5=>[5], 1=>[1], 2=>[2, 2], 6=>[6], 4=>[4]}
```

That way you can instantly see if the array for a given number is empty or not. Note that it's easy to do array differences in Ruby, which might help you with removing dice:

```
>> [3,1,3,5,1,7] - [3]  #=> [1, 5, 1, 7]
```

In fact array intersection also is a good way to see if a certain element is part of an array:

```
>> ([3,1,3,5,1,7] & [3]).empty? #=> false
>> ([4,1,2,5,1,7] & [3]).empty? #=> true
```

Some more tips: You don't need dummy statements for your `else` branches, you can just leave them out. I also strongly recommend going through the docs of `Array` and `Enumerable`, there's lot of useful methods in there.

Comment: I was just writing a reply with a "roll_dice" method and a bit of use of .select to get the threes out... but I think Michael's suggestion of having a play in the console with the methods from the API for Array and Enumerable is a great suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and encouragement. Emoticons go miles in the way of reassurance. I don't fully understand your answer yet, but I'll tackle it monday. With the help of ruby-doc.com I'm sure it'll elucidate a lot about ruby and coding in general and help set me on the path.

Answer (score 2):

BTW, Michael Kohl created methodfinder gem. so:

```
$ sudo gem install methodfinder
```

Now we can find method we need:

```
[2,3,2,3,4,3,2].find_method { |x| x.unknown(3) == [3,3,3] }
=> grep
```

So I'd write your algorithm like this:

```
def keep dice
  threes = dice.grep(3)
  threes.empty? ? [dice.min] : threes
end
```

Comment: @Bodhidarma, you need to install Ruby Gems. Here are my instructions, how to install RVM with Ruby Gems and Rails: http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/13251

Answer (score 1):

Of course there are many ways to do this. But have a look: I've made some general modifications to make it a bit more... Rubyish!

```
# A custom helper method
class Array
  def take_while_num # Modeled off take_while, but also pass in the length so far
    arr = []
    each do |e|
      # Call the block with this element and the current length,
      # and stop if it returns false
      if yield(e, arr.length)
        arr << e
      else
        break
      end
    end
    arr
  end
end

dice = Array.new(5) { rand(6)+1 } # 5 random numbers
puts "Original dice: #{dice.inspect}"

# Sort the dice by value (3s are worth 0), then take all 3s
# or if there are no 3s, take whatever is at the front
keep = dice.sort_by {|d| d == 3 ? 0 : d }.take_while_num {|d, n| n.zero? or d == 3 }
# Remove the ones we're keeping from the list of dice
dice -= keep

puts "Dice: #{dice.inspect}"
puts "Keep: #{keep.inspect}"
```

An example:

```
Original dice: [3, 2, 4, 3, 1]
Dice: [2, 4, 1]
Keep: [3, 3]
```